# Can a pthreads program's race condition crash the OS or X completely?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Or should one first look at the drivers involved (e.g. OpenGL drivers in a game) or the X server, or a kernel bug?

The example case is simple, two threads may be writing the same variable at the same time. Can that trigger such a massive lock up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of a decent operating system, definitely not. Any threading issues should be isolated to the current process only.

Assuming that process itself isn't inherently dangerous (elevated privileges, kernel mode code and so forth), it should not be able to bring the OS itself down.

Comment: It depends on your definition of "bring down".  Crashing the kernel should definitely not be possible, but queuing up so many I/O to the disk (and maybe allocating enough memory to cause swapping at the same time) that `xkill` can't start, might be.

Comment: @Ben: especially on typical Linux systems where overcommit is not disabled and ulimits are not set, resource bombs can really take down the system.

Comment: @R: Right, it isn't actually crashed, but its ability to provide services is nil since it's too busy swapping.

Answer (score 1):

Absent a bug, that should not crash the OS.

Now, a user-mode program with sufficiently high priority, or executing a denial-of-service attack (possibly unintentionally) can cause the system to hang, but that has nothing to do with race conditions, just the efficiency of generating requests vs the time needed for the X server to process them.

What does the shared variable control?  Is it simply used in mathematical calculations, or does it change the path through your code?